# Converting LinkedHashMap<dynamic,dynamic> to HashMap<String,List<String>> in dart or flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Hi I am new to flutter and dart. I am facing difficulty in typecasting maps. I have saved some data on Firestore in the format of `HashMap<String,List<String>>`. In my flutter app when I am fetching this data, I am getting it in the format of `LinkedHashMap<dynamic,dynamic>`. I want to convert this `LinkedHashMap` into a `HashMap<String,List<String>>`. Please help.

```
LinkedHashMap<dynamic,dynamic> mapUserWatchlistCompanies= documentSnapshot.data['Watchlist']; // Fetched data.

HashMap<String,List<String>> hashMapUserWatchlist = ???//How can it be converted? Need help here.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The typecast in dart it's a bit different than you would get in Java or Swift. In dart you have to correctly cast everything when `dynamic` is involved.

Now in your case you get a `LinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>`, now in JSON  case it's safe to assume that the keys will always be a `String` value, but the `value` for a key can be several types (number, string, boolean, map or list).

So if you have a JSON in the following form:

```
{
  "keyOne": ["One", "Two","whatever"],
  "keyTwp": ["roses", "are", "red"],
  "keyThree":["You", "know", "nothing", "john", "nonw"]
}
```

Which is a `HashMap<String, List<String>>`, but dart initially will get a `LinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>`, you can safely convert it with the following code:

```
 LinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic> theParsedOne = .....
    HashMap<String, List<String>> newMap = HashMap.from(theParsedOne.map((key, value) {
      List<dynamic> values = List.from(value);
      return MapEntry(
          key.toString(),
          values.map((theValue) {
            return theValue.toString();
          }).toList());
    }));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly `HashMap` is in your code but if you mean `Map` you can probably create map with this code:

```dart
Map<String, List<String>> values = Map<String, List<String>>.from(snap.data['Watchlist']);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It is throwing an exception - `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **convert** *any* Kind of **LinkedHashMap** into **Map**:

*Serializing* and *deserializing* it back to Map<String, dynamic> works.

```
final validMap =
        json.decode(json.encode(internalLinkedHashMap)) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```